# GitLab templating: Multiple default before_script blocks

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

This doesn't work correctly:

template1.yml

```
default:
   before_script:
      - echo "hello from one"
```

template2.yml

```
default:
   before_script:
      - echo "hello from two"
```

.gitlab-ci.yml (the actual pipeline)

```
include:
  - project: 'templates'
    file:
      - 'template1.yml'
      - 'template2.yml'
  
build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello from the pipeline"
```

output (note the output from template1 is missing):

```
Hello from two
hello from the pipeline
```

I understand that GitLab may believe that there is 'ambiguity' in the ordering when merging blocks in to before_script, but it could use the order specified in the 'include'
section of the pipeline.

Does anyone know of a way that I can arbitrarily include templates in my pipeline in such a way that they can contribute to the default 'before_script' block?

It all must run sequentially in the same container (be in the same 'stage')

For example, using yaml anchors requires us to specify the names of the anchors rather than just the file that the anchors were in, so that doesn't work...